# Problems when building an android app with gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am trying to understand how to build Android Apps without using and IDE, so basically starting from scratch. I discovered that a good way to build the Android App is to use Gradle.

So from command line, in the root of my project, I type "gradle wrapper" so it creates al the necessary files to use gradle, then i type "gradle init" and it creates the build.gradle text file where i have to put all the setting to build the project (i suppose). Here is what I put there searching on the internet.

```
// 1
buildscript {
    // 2
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    // 3
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.51'
    }
}

// 4
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

So I write on the command line, "./gradle AssembleDebug" to perform the build but it gives me theese errors.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/michelangelo/Documents/HelloAndroid/build.gradle' line: 5

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'HelloAndroid'.
> Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I've never done things like this before so i don't know what to do.

Comment: Try moving `classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.51'` from the project `build.gradle` to (hopefully) `app` `build.gradle`.

Comment: Which Android SDK version are you using? https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-plugin
Try using Gradle version 3.3.2.

Comment: MDNaseemAshraf i've tried but the problem remain the same. Onik i don't really understand where do i have to put that line of code. 
Do you think i have also to modify the settings.gradle file ? What should I put there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `./gradlew  AssembleDebug`. The Gradle wrapper (gradlew) itself is supposed to pick up your properties and pass it onto the gradle tool to run.

You should use the gradlew tool instead of using gradle directly.

See [Build your app from the command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline), the official Google guideline, states;

> You can execute all the build tasks available to your Android project
>   using the Gradle wrapper command line tool. It's available as a batch
>   file for Windows (gradlew.bat) and a shell script for Linux and Mac
>   (gradlew.sh), and it's accessible from the root of each project you
>   create with Android Studio.
>
> To run a task with the wrapper, use one of the following commands from
>   a Terminal window (from Android Studio, select View > Tool Windows >
>   Terminal):
>
> On Windows: `gradlew task-name`
>
> On Mac or Linux: `./gradlew task-name`

You can read about Gradle Wrapper in Gradle's [official documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html). Also read this blog post; [Understanding the Gradle Wrapper](https://medium.com/@bherbst/understanding-the-gradle-wrapper-a62f35662ab7).

You can also see how I build an Android app from just the project source files, some gradle properties and dependency files, on CircleCI system via command line instructions in [this](https://github.com/mdnaseemashraf/Memento2/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml) yml file.

Hope this helps you.